# Firebase query does not allow order on multiple properties?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch some data from firebase. In my object, I have

```
Recent
   |_UniversitId
       |_objectiId1
       |  |_ userId:1
       |  |_ timestamp:143242344
       |_objectiId2
          |_ userId:1
          |_ timestamp:143243222
```

My querying path is `http://firbasedbname.com/Recent/UniversityId`. I need to fetch the entries which are userId id is equal to 1 and order that set by timestamp. I tried the following,

```
FIRDatabaseQuery *query = [[firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"userId"] queryEqualToValue:@"1"];
```

This fetches my the users correctly. But is there a possible way to order this set by timestamp. To do that I tried by putting another `queryOrderedByChild`. But it says it can be used only one time. How may I fix this?

Comment: As Mohamed says (and David explains in the linked video) you can only order/filter on a single property with the Firebase Database. In your case it seems like you can combine the two values into a single property and filter on that. See my answer here for an example of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: I just expanded my answer to that question to include an example with a range query (`startAt` and `endAt`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

queryOrderedByChild can be used only once. 
a workaround would be

```
   |_objectiId1
   |  |_ userId:1
   |  |_ timestamp:143242344
   |  |_ userId_timestamp:1_143242344
   |_objectiId2
      |_ userId:1
      |_ timestamp:143243222
      |_ userId_timestamp:1_143243222
```

Then try :

```
FIRDatabaseQuery *query = [[firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"userId_timestamp"] queryEqualToValue:@"1_143242344"];
```

check this out https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=541

---

another way to do it would be :

```
 |_objectiId1
       |_ userId1:
       |      |_ objectId11:143242344
       |      |_ objectId12:143243222
       |_ userId2:
```

Then
querying path is `http://firbasedbname.com/Recent/UniversityId/userId1`

and then order by value

Comment: That's not going to work. The query will read in only the nodes that match 1_1432344 which is probably only 1.  Change the query to startingAt:@"1_" and endingAt:@"1_". That will retrieve all of the nodes for user id 1 ordering by the time stamp component of that node. Otherwise a good answer.