# How to filtering data for two values in FirebaseListAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am use Firebase DB and FirebaseListAdapter for display and filtering my data. But, my data is filtering *for ONE values (idUser)*. But, i want filtering data for TWO values **idUser** and **good** (show data where idUser=2 and good=true).
     Can i try it in android?

```
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Movie>(this, Movie.class,
                R.layout.item_movie, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("movies")
                .orderByChild("idUser")
                .equalTo("2"))
```

My database:

```
{
    "movies": {
        "1": {
            "name": "comedy",
            "idUser": "2",
            "good": "true"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Horror",
            "idUser": "2",
            "good": "false"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "comedy",
            "idUser": "2",
            "good": "true"
        }
      }  
     }
```

Comment: As Mohamed said, you can only have one `orderBy` clause in Firebase Database. You may be able to combine the values you want to filter on into a single property. See my answer here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, THANKS! I saw it's answer! But, If I am not mistaken, it's answer for JavaScript.

Comment: The approach is the same for any technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use order by once.

So the answer is to modify your schema.

See my answer to this question [multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44474765/7475652)

Comment: You mean that i need add new field `"idUser_good=2_true"` and get value of this field?

Comment: yes. 
and get it like that `.orderByChild("idUser_good")
                .equalTo("2_true"))`